# How to generate a regex with Max of 3 numeric chars before & after the "/" where Numbers before the "/" should be greater than numbers after the "/"

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have to generate a regex with following conditions

- Max of 3 numeric chars before and after the "/"  Max of 7 chars
- including "/" and no other special chars & decimals allowed
- Numbers before the "/" should be greater than numbers after the "/"

I have tried this so far

```
^\d{3}(\/\d{3})?$
```

How will I fix this validation on regex "Numbers before the "/" should be greater than numbers after the "/""?

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve this with a regular expression alone (at least, not that easily or readably) - instead, capture both digit parts, and check that the first digits are greater than the second:

```js
const check = str => {
  const match = str.match(/^(\d{1,3})\/(\d{1,3})$/);
  if (!match) {
    return false;
  }
  const [, d1, d2] = match;
  return Number(d1) > Number(d2);
};

console.log(
  check('123/456'),
  check('456/123'),
  check('45/123'),
  check('12/45')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign two variables  - One for the digits before '/' and one for after.
like A/B, then use split() function with '-' as the delimiter and then compare the two parts with >.

As far as I know, numeric values cannot be compared in Regex.